# How to extract the 'src' attribute as per the html through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, getattribute

I have a html page:

```
<video crossorigin="anonymous" class="" id="video" playsinline="true" 
       src="https://df.dfs.bnt.com/
       DEEAB832j06E9j413FjAA8Dj2zxc535DA2072E3jW01j15579/mp4- 
       hi/jFNf2IbBoGF28IzyU_WqkA,1535144598/zxxx/
       contents/1/8/1a57ae021173751b468cca136e0192.mp4? 
       rnd=0.38664488150364296"> 
</video>
```

Through Selenium WebDriver I tried get video url:

```
By videoLocator = By.id("video");
WebElement videoElement = driver.findElement(videoLocator);
String videoUrl = videoElement.getAttribute("src");
```

But **videoUrl** - always returns **""**(is empty).

Нowever for example:

```
videoElement.getAttribute("crossorigin")
```

return correct answer: "**anonymous**".

I have tried get this url from src attribute using javascript:

```
String videoUrl = (String) js.executeScript("return document.getElementById( 'video' ).getAttribute( 'src' );");
```

But the result is still the same: **""**.

I guess that the problem is in **crossorigin="anonymous"** but what to do with it? How can I get src value?

Sorry, for my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have provided you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement videoElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//video[@id='video' and @crossorigin='anonymous'][starts-with(@src,'http')]")));
System.out.println(videoElement.getAttribute("src"));
```

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for value to contain "https". Current value: "null" (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)`

Comment: @GSV Checkout my updated answer and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching innerHTML attribute. Code :

```
By videoLocator = By.id("video");
WebElement videoElement = driver.findElement(videoLocator);
String videoUrl = videoElement.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```